# Hacer que un menu funcione en un ciclo for (python)

Tags: python, funciones, bucle-for, class, menu

tengo este programa que da al usuario el calculo de complejidad algoritmica de tres opciones dadas en el menú, 10, 100 y 1000. Tengo el problema que cuando voy a dar el print no se como llamar la opcion del usuario y calcularlo. Hice el programa de otra forma dando un ciclo if a cada opción del menú pero me pareció muy largo y repetitivo. Entonces decidí por hacerlo con un class y varias funciones, y es ahí donde quede quieto sin saber que hacer Aprecio la ayuda en este pequeño proyecto. Gracias

```
import math


class complejidad_algoritmica():
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def constante(self):
        return 1

    def lineal(self):
        return self.n

    def logaritmica(self):
        return math.log10(self.n)

    def log_lineal(self):   
        return self.n * math.log10(self.n)

    def polinomial(self):
        return self.n ** 2

    def exponencial(self):
        return 2 ** self.n


def main():
    menu = """
    para entender mejor el BIG O NOTATION
    
    a. 10
    b. 100
    c. 1000

    Elije una opción de esta lista: """

    opcion = input(menu)

    #n = [10, 100, 1000]
    for i in opcion:
        complejidad = complejidad_algoritmica(opcion)

        if opcion == 'a' or opcion == 'b' or opcion == 'c':

            print(f'O(1) es {complejidad.constante()}')
            print(f'O(n) es igual {complejidad.lineal()}')
            
            print(f'O(log n) es {complejidad.logaritmica()}')
            print(f'O(n log n) es {complejidad.log_lineal()}')

            print(f'O(n**2) es igual a {complejidad.polinomial()}')
            print(f'O(2**n) es igual a {complejidad.exponencial()}')

        else:
            print('Elige una opción válida: a, b, c')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

así lo estaba haciendo al principio, pero solo era para mi, después decidí hacerlo con opción menú y print, y ahí comenzó el enredo

```
n = [10, 100, 1000]
i = 0
for numbers in n:
    print(num(n[i]))
    print(logarithm(n[i]))
    print(lineal(n[i]))
    print(n_logarithm(n[i]))
    print(square(n[i]))
    print(exponential(n[i]))
    print('\n')
    i+=1
```

Comment: @revliscano, gracias por la edición, cuando lo publique no se porque se dividió en tres partes el código y estaba muy cansado que no supe como arreglarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como `opcion` es una cadena, la instrucción

```
for i in opcion:
```

hará una iteración, donde la variable `i` tomara el valor `a`, `b` o `c` ingresado por el usuario.

```
opcion = input(menu)
```

El `for` itera cambiando `i`, pero nunca usas `i` dentro del `for`, lo que indica un problema de lógica: ¿para qué iterar si no lo vas a usar.

En fin, aqui hay una versión de `main`que probablemente sea lo que buscas:

```
def main():
    menu = """
    para entender mejor el BIG O NOTATION

    a. 10
    b. 100
    c. 1000

    Elije una opción de esta lista: """

    while True:
        opcion = input(menu).strip()
        if opcion == 'a':
            complejidad = complejidad_algoritmica(10)
        elif opcion == 'b':
            complejidad = complejidad_algoritmica(100)
        elif opcion == 'c':
            complejidad = complejidad_algoritmica(1000)
        else:
            print('Elige una opción válida: a, b, c')
            continue

        print(f'O(1) es {complejidad.constante()}')
        print(f'O(n) es igual {complejidad.lineal()}')

        print(f'O(log n) es {complejidad.logaritmica()}')
        print(f'O(n log n) es {complejidad.log_lineal()}')

        print(f'O(n**2) es igual a {complejidad.polinomial()}')
        print(f'O(2**n) es igual a {complejidad.exponencial()}')
```

produce:

```
    para entender mejor el BIG O NOTATION

    a. 10
    b. 100
    c. 1000

    Elije una opción de esta lista: a
O(1) es 1
O(n) es igual 10
O(log n) es 1.0
O(n log n) es 10.0
O(n**2) es igual a 100
O(2**n) es igual a 1024
```

Comment: Bro, esta excelente la solución, nunca se me paso por la mente el bucle while. y Tenes razón con el for, me estaba enredando solo. Voy a leer sobre el .strip es primera vez que lo veo, se ve muy util.